# The distance between the orbit and the $\omega$-limitset

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Suppose $\omega(\gamma)$ is the $\omega$-limitset of $\gamma:x(t,x_0)$ and it is compact. I want to prove the distance $d(x(t,x_0),\omega(\gamma))\rightarrow 0$ when $t\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: If you do not assume that $\omega(\gamma)$ is compact the property need not be true: see fig. 1.3.11 on p. 31 of  Bhatia and Szegö [Stability Theory of Dynamical Systems](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540427483).

Comment: @user539887 sorry.i edit it

Comment: Do you assume that the phase space is locally compact?